# React Native Expo-Image-Picker base64 too slowly

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I'm saving pictures with the help of expo image picker and axios, but the base64 storage part in the database is very long and naturally it takes a long time to load when listing the images on a screen. **What can I do to make images load faster?**

**Example code:**

```
 const PickImage2 = async () => {
   allowPhotoRequests()

let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 0.5,
  base64: true
})

if (!result.cancelled) {
  setImage('data:image/jpg;base64,' + result.base64)
}
```

}

**Example image output:**

```
data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARzQklUCAgICHwIZIgAACAASURBVHic7N13nFxV3cfxzzn33mm7szVbUjYhCSGFFAhVQomidEQEBR6Qpg8gIvYHxA764AMWrI8FG1hA9FHpRR
```

Comment: Can you upload images to cloud storage providers like AWS  S3 or  Firebase Storage?  Storing  heavy base64 string in database not scalable

Comment: Do I need to use these services just to keep photos? or do i need to move the whole database to one of these services? @BYIRINGIRO Emmanuel

Comment: Keep photo only. You don't have to migrate a whole database there